# 2nd Wheel Bearing in 14 months. Do I have an underlying issue?

Tags: brakes, chrysler, wheel-bearing, town-and-country

We were finishing a cross-country trip in our 2014 Chrysler Town and Country (80k miles) and I could feel some jitter on braking at high speed. I also thought I felt some vibration once in a while with no braking. So, I brought the car to our usual mechanics, who've been pretty good over the years.

They told me that we needed new brake pads and rotors up front (not a surprise, we needed them in the rear last year) but that we also needed a new wheel bearing, front, driver side. I told them to check the records because I thought we'd replaced that one last year, and they said yeah, they did, June of 2021. They said the play they detect in it is fairly significant (not that I'd be OK with even minor bearing problems) but it makes me wonder if there's a potential underlying issue making those go bad? (As a human, it's my job to consider 2 things a trend!)

We had the tires replaced about a month ago, and the front treadwear appeared consistent with a little bit too much toe-in up there, but that's the only other thing I can think of. The car generally only drives about 15 miles a day, standard suburban driving, and one big trip a year. We're 2nd owners, got it at Carmax 5 years ago or so. No significant issues thus far.